# Six sigma quality management and software development

Tags: agile

Is it possible to use Six Sigma Quality Management with Software Development Processes?

What's your experience on that?

If you're using an Agile method like Scrum or XP, isn't Six Sigma too bureaucratic?

I'm talking about quality management on software development as a whole, since requirements gathering until deployoment and operations, and not only the construction phase (which tools like TDD and unit testing are more or less already established as best practices).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about project management, not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Six Sigma works well with reproducible processes. By that, I mean pure process that consistently produces (or is supposed to produce) the same output. Given that software development rarely produces the same output, SS is not really applicable, IMO. This is because software development is more a practice than a process.

That being said, it doesn't hurt to read about it and try to see what top-level ideas can be put into software development...

Answer (score 11):

If I understand it correctly, six sigma depends on having meaningful, measurable metrics.  What will yours be?   KLOC?  Classes checked into your archive?  Agile velocity?

Six sigma works great on shop floors, but I don't believe that software development is sufficiently "widget-like" to lend itself to such an approach.

Comment: Not more than 3.4 defects per million LOC :)

Comment: Notice that you're talking only about construction-related processes. Think more about Concept-to-Cash quality management.

Comment: I'm not sure "Concept-To-Cash" concept is, but I'm sure it involves cashing in. :) Has that "so vague it means anything you want" kind of smell.

Comment: I'm sorry: it means from the moment you identify the idea, concept, vision, requirements until you deploy the finished product to your customer.

Comment: @Dema - That was clear; the metrics were not.  If I understand it correctly, that's what alphadogg meant by "vague".

Answer (score 7):

It is definitely possible as long as you aren't developing a new product.

Just follow these steps.

1) Create a bug free version of the application. This may take a considerable amount of effort thus it is best to select an application that is trivial in scope.
2) Recreate the application from scratch and compare the iteration to the ideal created in step 1 to create a metric.
3) Tweak your process to acheive closer alignment next to the metric on the next iteration.
4) Go to step 2.

What? You don't create the same application over and over in your shop? Hmm, I don't think six sigma is going to be much use in that scenario.

Answer (score 4):

For Six Sigma to be useful you need easily comparable metrics or procedures.

Software is too abstract to have the type of metrics needed.

Maybe a good question to ask would be

> Is there a quality control tool for software development similar to Six Sigma for the production and manufacturing world?

Comment: Ok, so suppose the question was the one you stated. Could you answer it? ;-)

Comment: No I don't think I can.  There are some great books like Code Complete and others but not a tool like Six Sigma that I am aware of.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a wide range of methodologies, Six Sigma, Agile etc.  Really the success of quality management on software development is dependent on one key thing.  The quailty of the team.  It all boils down to that.  A good team can work within a horrible methodology and make it work.  That's why they are good.  Process is important, and you can make a bad process more efficient, but it's all dependent on the team.

Comment: Yep, people first, management buzzwords later!

Comment: Of course, people is the #1 factor. In an utopic world, we'd all work with perfect, hyper-competent people! ;-) But even with good people, in a large project with a long production chain, you have to manage quality variations all along.

Comment: But that's the point no matter what methodology you use, it is going to work or not work largly because of the people.  The style of methodoly is really immaterial.  A good methodolgy will most likely faile with bad people.

Answer (score 2):

There are parts of software development that don't fit well, as they do not provide a process with a normal distribution of results. On the other hand, the focus on risk, value and doing the right things is essential

[edit] Take a look at the Cynefin model (on wikipedia) to understand why large parts of software development are in the complex domain.

Answer (score 2):

Six Sigma can be a good fit for maintenance teams that have a big backlog of discrete work items.

Design for Six Sigma has some elements that can be applied to building a new software product.

And since most software is an enabler to a business process, and that business process may be a highly repeated process where the statistics tools of six sigma can be applied, six sigma can have a role in determining what the highest value software feature is to deliver maximal business value.  It can take the emotion out of the decision making process for feature prioritization.  If you have an environment where the product manager/stakeholder who yells loudest or most eloquently got their stuff built, six sigma can be applied to fix that unhealthy aspect of your development process by putting some rational measurement behind the prioritization process.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to follow you.

[SixSigma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Sigma) is a is a methodology to manage **process variations** that uses data and statistical analysis to measure and improve a company's operational performance.

So take any process (SDP or other), choose what you want to measure, identify the issues, plan the solutions, evaluate the impacts.

The SixSigma projects I have participated were all fairly transversal and not linked to a software life cycle.

---

By transversal, I mean transversal to the "product design-development-construction-delivery" process that is software development.

For example, in an environment were we need to produce a set of programs running on our internal production platform, most of our SixSigma projects are centered around **[Operational Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122931#123132)**, that is "making operational an execution environment" (how to set up servers and networks in order to stop, update, install and launch a set of executables, and that for many projects each with their own SDP).
That is a notion transversal to any SDP you want, since in the end, all those "Development Processes" have but one goal in common: put your software into production.

The criteria to measure were precise and reproducible, going from the time to manage the merges needed to consolidate a final executable to the number of merge errors to the deployment errors (because of an incorrect labels or a faulty release notes).

All those missteps were noted release after release, and the goal was to reduce them.
One side-effect was to identify an inadequate [merge workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216212#216228), workflow which, once fixed, allowed us to greatly reduce the errors in the final set of deliveries.

Comment: If you think software development more like a kind of product design-development-construction-delivery, it is normally a transversal process.

Answer (score 0):

I had a professor in a class that taught six sigma and other manufacturing efficiency techniques, and after telling him I was in the software development field he suggested the book [Lean Software Development](http://books.google.com/books?id=8o1eom6ifIMC&dq=lean+software+development&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=ra16S6ihG5CjngfPwaj4DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false).  Unforunately I haven't read it, but it seems to deal with applying some of the *applicable* concepts of six sigma and lean manufacturing to producing software (like eliminating waste, reducing defects, continuous improvement).  [Here's](http://www.projectperfect.com.au/info_lean_development.php) a short white paper describing lean software development.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Six Sigma for specific performance testing projects which begin with a specific measurable problem statement and end with a counter measure that is again measurable. The DMAIC lends itself to performance tuning, as do the tools and techniques of Causal Analysis, Design of Experiments etc.