# Dev Tools or Config Tools?

Tags: svn, teamcity, nexus

What are these tools called - Mingle, Subversion, TeamCity, Nexus

Are these the dev tools or config services tools?
Not sure whether they are dev tools because dev tools might include other developer applications for e.g. IDE (eclipse/IntelliJ IDEA)

Answer (score 1):

They are **development tools**, in the sense they are directly involved in the development process.
The fact they can be used to also managed the configuration is but one aspect of their application in said development process.

I manage them (in term of administration, installation, support...) in a ["Development Architecture" team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212270#212362) (with [various Architecture teams detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122931/setting-up-an-architecture-department/123132#123132)), along with other tools (IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse or Visual Studio), and other more generic tools (text editors, diff tools, ...)